# collect output of batch file without prompt

Tags: batch-file, pipe, dos

When I run a batch file, the output contains the command prompt for each command executed.  I want to collect the command executed, but I don't want the prompt (which is the directory).  I can `sed -e 's/^.:[^>]*>'` to remove the prompt but might remove some valid output too.

Is there a way to not echo the directory from which the command is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the prompt (see `prompt /?`) in your script. This example sets the prompt to a single space.

```
SETLOCAL
prompt $S

:: do stuff
```

I don't know how to change the prompt to *nothing*, but if you want the output to be readable, I'd probably change it to something short and unique, like `>>>`:

```
SETLOCAL
prompt $G$G$G$S
```

For example, this script

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

PROMPT $G$G$G$S

dir /b
time /t
date /t
```

produces this output:

```
>>> dir /b 
bang.cmd
bang.txt
date1.cmd
list.txt
list_complete.txt
pmpt.cmd
q2.cmd
temp.zip
temp_orig.zip
timetest.cmd
z.cmd

>>> time /t 
01:17 PM

>>> date /t 
Fri 06/28/2013
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the prompt. See http://www.computerhope.com/prompthl.htm. You can set it, for instance, to `$_` (carriage return and linefeed): `prompt $_`, or `$H` (backspace): `prompt $H`. I don't know if there's a way to set it to empty.